# Checking if a element is focused (has outline around it) with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked everywhere but cannot find an answer. How can I check that if a certain element is focused (i.e. outline is around the element.), then focus the next element, if not then the focus should stay where it is? For example I have a list of 5 form elements (i.e. input, label, button, etc...); if the 3rd element is focused then put focus on the 4th element, if not carry on as normal. This is for when the user navigates through the list with the tab key on the keyboard and it's the label that gets focused:

JS:

```
var thisElem = $(this),
    viewport = thisElem.find('.expand-viewport'),
    viewportHeight = viewport.height(),
    wrapper = viewport.find('ul.expand-wrapper'),
    wrapperLi = wrapper.find('li'),
    liLen = wrapperLi.length,
    numShown = thisElem.find('[data-view="showhide"]').data('showalways');

for (var i = 0; i < liLen; i += 1) {

  if ($(wrapperLi[i]).eq(numShown - 1).children('label').is(':focus')) {     
    $(wrapperLi[i]).eq(numShown - 1).next().children('label').focus();
    console.log('go to label in next li item');                
  } else {
      thisElem.children('label').focus();
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="features" class="expand-viewport">
        <ul class="expand-wrapper">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Smartphone (36)" id="featureSmartPhone" name="featureSmartPhone" />
                <label for="featureSmartPhone">Smartphone (36)</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3G (42)" id="feature3g" name="feature3g" />
                <label for="feature3g">3G (42)</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Bluetooth (63)" id="featureBluetooth" name="featureBluetooth" />
                <label for="featureBluetooth">Bluetooth (63)</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Camera (64)" id="featureCamera" name="featureCamera" />
                <label for="featureCamera">Camera (64)</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Email (63)" id="featureEmail" name="featureEmail" />
                <label for="featureEmail">Email (63)</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#less" class="more" data-moreorless="true">More</a>
    </div>
```

I hope I'm on the right direction with my code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts in this :

First of all, you can use `tabindex="0"`  to set the tabbing order, and can bypass a label.

Also, `disabled` elements do not receive tab attention, so you can use that.

This is easier to handle tabs that way than use jQuery as you do.

References :

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex
  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#disabled

Comment: I know we can use tabindex, etc but I'm doing something that requires me to use jquery when it's on. I have to use jquery. So what's the solution?

Comment: But why would you want to use jQuery when you don't have to? This is trivial to go by using simply html and the browser itself.

Comment: As I said I'm doing something complex that requires me to use jquery. I haven't included the other parts of my code for simplicity. All I want is someone to help me do this in jquery, so I can carry on...